# How to close all Chrome windows opened by Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, testng

I am running Selenium tests using testNG and ChromeDriver. 
I have to perform a large set of tests, all of them start by opening a new Chrome window via Selenium.

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  "src//main//java//resources//" + getSeleniumChromeDriver());
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        if(incognito){
            options.addArguments("--incognito");
        }
        browser = new ChromeDriver(options);
        String URL = "http://" + PersoneticsTestPropsReader.getValue("pserverHost") + ":8080/padmin/index.html";
        browser.get(URL);
```

How can I close all Chrome windows that my code opened, and not Chrome windows that were opened manually by any user?

Answer (score 2):

You need to preserve all the references to `driver` objects to the moment you'd like to close everything.

Then iterate over that set and invoke

`driver.quit()` (or probably `browser.quit()` in your case) for all the objects of the set.

This will close only automated windows, but not the ones have been opened manually.